# remove duplicates within the string

Tags: r

I want to remove duplicates within the string. For e.g. `Predictive Modeling` is a duplicated value in the first row. Need to make sure after removing duplicates, string does not have extra `,`

```
mydf <- data.frame(Keyword = c("Predictive Modeling, R, Python, Predictive Modeling, SQL, Tableau, data analysis", "SQL, Tableau, data analysis, data analysis", "Predictive Modeling, Python, SQL, visualization, Spark, Tableau"))
```

**Desired Output**

```
mydf <- data.frame(Keyword = c("Predictive Modeling, R, Python, SQL, Tableau, data analysis", "SQL, Tableau, data analysis", "Predictive Modeling, Python, SQL, visualization, Spark, Tableau"))
```

Comment: Please include the output you expect after removing "duplicates."

Comment: Sure, Added the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach using `strsplit`:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(Keyword = c("Predictive Modeling, R, Python, Predictive Modeling, SQL, Tableau, data analysis", "SQL, Tableau, data analysis, data analysis"))

mydf$Keyword <- unlist(
  lapply(strsplit(mydf$Keyword, ", "),
         function(x) paste(unique(x),
                           collapse = ", "))
  )

mydf
#>                                                       Keyword
#> 1 Predictive Modeling, R, Python, SQL, Tableau, data analysis
#> 2                                 SQL, Tableau, data analysis
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here a one-liner using `toString`.

```
transform(mydf, Keyword=sapply(strsplit(Keyword, ', '), \(x) toString(unique(x))))
#                                                           Keyword
# 1     Predictive Modeling, R, Python, SQL, Tableau, data analysis
# 2                                     SQL, Tableau, data analysis
# 3 Predictive Modeling, Python, SQL, visualization, Spark, Tableau
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex based approach.  We can replace any CSV term, which also appears later in the string, with empty string.

```r
mydf <- data.frame(Keyword = c("Predictive Modeling, R, Python, Predictive Modeling, SQL, Tableau, data analysis", "SQL, Tableau, data analysis, data analysis"))
mydf$Keyword <- gsub("\\s*([^,]+),?(?=.*\\1(?:,|$))", "", 
mydf$Keyword, perl=TRUE)
mydf

1  R, Python, Predictive Modeling, SQL, Tableau, data analyis
2                                  SQL, Tableau, data analyis
```

Notr that this approach retains the *last* instance of a CSV term, but maybe this is acceptable for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It does not give desired output (truncated values) for example if I use "Predictive Modeling, Python, SQL, visualization, Spark, Tableau" It returns "Predictive Modelig, Pyth SQL, visalization, Spark, Tableau". See truncated "Pyth SQL" and "Modelig"

Comment: This is not the question which was asked nor what was answered.  You didn't ask about substring and partial duplicates.

Comment: I asked about duplicated words. It does not work on duplicated words

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(Keyword, sep =",\\s+") %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  summarise(Keyword = toString(Keyword), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  Keyword                                                        
  <chr>                                                          
1 Predictive Modeling, R, Python, SQL, Tableau, data analysis    
2 SQL, Tableau, data analysis                                    
3 Predictive Modeling, Python, SQL, visualization, Spark, Tableau
```